# Android actionbar tabs compatibility with 2.2

Tags: android, tabs, compatibility, android-actionbar

Hi i have rectly start working with android 4.0's action bar and tabs but when i trying to open the app on 2.2 it crashes. And i wonder how i should do so it can be compatible with 2.2+
Is it like layout for diffrent versions like you name a foler v8-layout or somethig like that?

thanks and sorry for my english grammar :)

Answer (score 4):

The action bar does not exist on Android 2.x. Any attempts to reference the `ActionBar` class will result in a `VerifyError`.

If you want to have an action bar on Android 2.x as well as your Android 3.0+ applications, you will need to use some extra code, such as [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com).

Comment: I know but shouldnt android just make my tabs to tabs like in 2.2?

Comment: In this case, app, built for 4.0 uses some classes and api, that is not present in 2.2. So, it's up to you - provide alternative implementation or just change minSdkVersion. Look at ActionBar example from 4.x samples.

Comment: @user986473: That would require a time machine, and mine is in the shop.